# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection. when routing with Eureka client discovery, after deploy on tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have 3 microservices as follows producer, zuul, and eureka. producer has one api called /employee which returns one JSONObject, but i want it to route through zuul so i am using **zuul.routes.producer.ur**l=http://localhost:8082 and its working fine but instead of hard coding zuul.route, i am using eureka for client discovery. when i am testing it in eclipse everything works fine, but after deploy all microservices in external tomcat and hitting /employee i am getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection".In tomcat's server.xml  https port are commented, even i tried **server.ssl.enabled=false** but result is same.I have no idea what is causing SSLException? Thanx in advance.

eureka pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.profinch</groupId>
    <artifactId>eurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>eurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Eureka</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
    <finalName>eureka</finalName>
        <plugins>

        </plugins>
    </build>     
</project>
```

eureka application.properties:

```
server.port=8099
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: http://localhost:8099/eureka
spring.application.name=eureka
hystrix
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

zuul pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee-zuul-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
    <finalName>zuul</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

zuul application.properties:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8099/eureka
server.port=8097
spring.application.name=zuul
server.ssl.enabled=false
hystrix
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Tomcat logs are:

```
[io-8082-exec-42] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:145) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)  
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]         
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)  
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]        
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)  [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.1 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.10]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:123) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:42) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6
.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10] 
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:377) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:343) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEAS
E]
        ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:58) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:465) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        ... 168 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.ja
r:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.6.RELEASE.ja
r:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:109) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        ... 170 common frames omitted
```

We are testing this on development environment so there is no https URLs but only http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. by adding property 
**ribbon.eureka.enabled=false**  in zuul every thing is working fine.